# Передача по указателю

Tags: c++

```
class B { ... }

class A {
public:
B * arr;
A() {
    arr = new B[10];
}
~A() {
    delete [] arr;
}
B * get() const {
   return arr;
}
}

int main () {
   A * a = new A;
   B * b = a->get();
   delete a;
}
```

Нужно ли дописывать delete b?

Класс B не имеет оператора и конструктора копирования.

Comment: `delete arr` —> `delete[] arr`

Comment: исправил..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в данном случае не нужно, объект уже создан и вы всеголишь получили на него указатель, только стоит понимать что после delete a, вам уже нельзя работать с объектом b.

Comment: @nanotexnik при наличии оператора или конструктора копирования в классе B нужно?

Comment: @andey1321, только если луна находится в 4-ой фазе.

Comment: @andey1321 Нет, в любом случае. Когда вы делаете new - выделение памяти, ваш get() - говорит где эта память находится (но не выделяет её заного), удаление памяти произойдет в деструкторе класса A.